# fake a mousedown with left button in WPF

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

I have a control in WPF
I want to fake a mousedown on that control, with left mouse button
I am trying 
myControl.OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1,0,0,0))

but it give me that "Cannot access protected method here"

anybody have idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use `IInputControl.RaiseEvent` method:

```
control.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(...))
```

Note that if you actually need to simulate a general click (i.e. regardless of whether it's performed by mouse, keyboard, touch input, or other method), or other *high-level* interaction with the control, you should probably use WPF Automation API instead.